# How can i set a default color to my MFC colorbutton control?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I want to add pink as a default color to my MFC colorbutton instead of black.

```
void TabOne::OnBnClickedColor()
{
    // TODO: Add your control notification handler code here
    CMFCColorButton* thisbutton = (CMFCColorButton*)GetDlgItem(Color);
    COLORREF ref = RGB(255, 0, 255);
    thisbutton->SetColor(ref);
    thisbutton->UpdateWindow();
}
```

it doesn't change the color.

Comment: How do you declare `Color` and how do you create the button? In resource editor you can drag and drop "MFC color button" in to the dialog, then Visual Studio may assign `IDC_MFCCOLORBUTTON1` to that button's id, and you would need `GetDlgItem(IDC_MFCCOLORBUTTON1)`

Comment: I changed IDC_MFCCOLORBUTTON1 to Color so Color now the id of my MFC color button.

Comment: Show the rest of your code. `OnBnClickedColor` looks like a response to the color button and is the wrong place to change the default color. You want to override `BOOL CMyDialog::OnInitDialog` to change default.